# How to send POST request with html form I got from another request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to simulate browser authorisation...

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Working...</title>
      </head>
      <body>
            <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="".../>
      </body>
</html>
```

I am getting html page with form which is sending data with token an other info to another domain... need to simulate that POST request with python.

Can someone suggest the best way to send that request without fetching data?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by without fetching data?

Comment: I mean that I don't want to parse every input and value manually...

Comment: Depends whether you want to do that from a single website or several ones. In the former case you could spot where these informations are located in the received html and parse them using [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for instance. Then you'd be able to send a request with all required informations. However, for the later case, I do not have a solution that works all the time. That would be on a per-case basis unfortunately...